# Spring integration test with context hierarchy child context bean as application listener

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am new to Spring, forgive me if I am doing something silly. I am trying to write an integration test for my application which uses spring.

I am creating a context hierarchy, as follows

```
  @Before
  public void setup(){
     parentContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);
     // some more setup stuff here
  }
```

In my test method, I am trying to create a new child context that has just one bean which is an application listener, that depends on beans in parent method.

```
public void test(){
    childContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    childContext.setParent(ctx);
    register(TestConfig2.class);
    childContext.refresh();
    // some testing stuff here that generates events
}
```

The problem I am facing is that my bean from the child context is not getting notified on application events also my @Value annotations are not processed.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out what was going wrong. My event publisher was in the parent context. I read on the spring forum, that spring context hierarchies work like class loaders. As in any beans loaded by the child Context are not visible to the parent context.

So I had to manually add the applicationlistener to the parent context.

```
parentContext.addApplicationListener(messageListener);
```

If want my childContext beans to get properties from parentContext I had to add the parentContext's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as a beanFactoryPostProcessor.

```
  configurer = parentContext.getBean(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
  childContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
```

to sum it up, I had to do the following in my test method

```
public void test(){
    childContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    childContext.setParent(parentContext);
    register(TestConfig2.class);
    configurer = parentContext.getBean(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
    childContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
    childContext.refresh();

    MessageListener messageListener = childContext.getBean(MessageListener.class);
    parentContext.addApplicationListener(messageListener);

    // some testing stuff here that generates events
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;
```

at the method @Before

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/application-Context.xml");
}
```

at the methode @After

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    context.close();
}
```

your method test

```
@Test
public void Test() {
    //Your Code Here
}
```

I am also starting in spring

Comment: I need two separate contexts. One is my main context that has all my beans. My second context one more bean.